# javascript unixtime one minute in front

Tags: javascript, time, unix-timestamp

Hi I'm passing a unixtimestamp to a javascript IF statement, can anyone tell me how to generate a unixtimestamp one minute in the future with javascript.

Anyhelp would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_date.asp) has a `getTime()` method that returns milliseconds since 1970. To make this look like a UNIX timestamp, you need to divide by 1000 and round (with `Math.floor())`. Adding 60 get's your one minute ahead.

```
var d = new Date();
var unixtimeAdd60 = Math.floor(d.getTime()/1000)+60;
```

Answer (score 1):

UNIX time is just the number of seconds since 1970-01-01Z. So just add 60 you'll get a timestamp one minute later.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript `Date` object's [`getTime`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) returns the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970.

Try this.

```
var oneMinLater = new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000;
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(oneMinLater);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the unix timestamp (this is time in seconds from 1/1/1970) in a simple way its:

```
var myDate = new Date();
    console.log(+myDate + 60); // you just sum the seconds that you want
    // +myDateObject give you the unix from that date
```